# How do I enter a literal tab character in a bash shell?

Tags: bash

I wanted to use the sort utility with the `-t` option to specify tab separators, but

```sh
sort -t "\t"
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Why won't '\011' work? Tried it on my Linux box and for some reason it doen't work.

Comment: I tried \t and it doesn't work, neither does \n, Is there a csh switch to turn off escaped characters? If there is, I've never heard of it.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Don't use double quotes.

`sort -t $'\t'`

Or I think Ctrl V inserts a Tab??

Edit:

http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting

Comment: Doesn't tab insert a tab?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Tab completes.

Comment: Control-V alone won't work; Control-V + Tab will. I like the `$'...'` trick, though; now *I've* learned something new. :-)

Comment: I've always learned it as `$' '`. It allows you to enter a string, but also have escaped characters.  Double quoting literally prints `\t` If you leave off the quotes you get a tab character.

Comment: won't work in dash

Comment: good to know, thanks :) -- I also discovered that: echo $'\t' is different from echo "$'\t'" -- that seems a bit weird, since normally $something works the same, with or without douiblequotes....

Answer (score 74):

Try <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>, then <kbd>Tab</kbd>. If you see the cursor tab over to the right, it worked.

According to the comment by Mark you can also try <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> and then <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd>.

Comment: When I do this, I get a real tab (i.e. indentation).

Comment: Oops. You're right. But it *is* entering the tab character, not doing command-line completion (which is what bash normally does with a tab). I tried `sort -t "       "` (with the literal tab as described above) and it worked for me.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant by indentation. Didn't know a better term.

Comment: Ctrl-v, Ctrl-i will also work (I found this answer [here](http://ask.metafilter.com/18273/tab-character-in-linux)).  Also, I think a Ctrl-q, Ctrl-v, Tab will work.  Thanks L2G!

Comment: BTW, I would love to accept both answers, but since I think surfasb's solution is more readable, I accepted hers.  I like yours, too, though, so voted it up.  Thanks!

Comment: why does the `ctrl-v then tab` and `ctrl-v then ctrl-i` work? what part of the `bash` man page describes why?

Comment: what if my clipboard is full...
and ctrl-q is a terrible idea, closes application

Answer (score 1):

### To put tab:

- First press `Ctr` + `v` and
- Then press  `tab` key.

---

### Example

Using above mentioned step adding tab
[image]

Saving in file
[image]

Final Output
[image]

---

Reference: https://linuxjourney.com/lesson/cut-command

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [printf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html):

```bsh
sort -t "$(printf "\t")"
```

Not like `$'\t'`, `printf` use **double quotes** which allow you to use **environment variables**, like below:

```bsh
char="\t" # any source just plain text

sort -t "$(printf "$char")"
```

Single quote is static and not flexible, though it's simple, you can choose based on your requirement.